# Como Desabilitar um dos itens de um TlistBox!

Tags: delphi, delphi-10

Queria Saber ser tem como Desabilitar um dos itens de um TlistBox.
E já tentei das seguintes maneiras e não tive Sucesso.

```
ListBoxMenu.ItemIndex(0).Enabled := False;
ListBoxMenu.ItemIndex[0].Enabled := False;
```

Quando eu ponho essas Linhas apresenta essa msg.

> [dcc32 Error] UntPrincipal.pas(6420): E2016 Array type required

Já tem tentei pesquisar sobre no site da http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/ mais não encontrei nada que me ajudasse.

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com a documentação, a propriedade [ItemIndex](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.ListBox.TCustomListBox.ItemIndex), especifica o Index do Item selecionado. Logo, ela retorna um inteiro e não o Item em si.

Para recuperar o item você pode usar o método [ItemByIndex](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.ListBox.TCustomListBox.ItemByIndex), ou a propriedade [ListItems](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.ListBox.TCustomListBox.ListItems).

Ficando assim:

```
ListBoxMenu.ItemByIndex(0).Enabled := False;
```

ou assim

```
ListBoxMenu.ListItems[0].Enabled := False;
```

Isso considerando que você está usando Firemonkey, que da uma liberdade maior de trabalhar com os itens pelo fato dos mesmo serem TListBoxItem.

Agora se estiver usando VCL onde os itens da ListBox são as linhas de uma TStrings.
Ai complica. Se for este o caso sugiro que remova o item da lista ao invés de tentar desabilitar.

Comment: Não Teria com ao menus mudar a cor de cada item do TListBox?